# Dialogflow failing to dectect the correct intent

Tags: android-intent, nlp, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

I am currently trying to create a basic chatbot using dialogflow. I created an intent to get order id from the user with numbers trained in it, but when ever i test it with numbers it goes to Default fallback intent.

PLease Help!! I have been struggling with this for 2 days and cant proceed further.